# Run keyword if to append to a string ... ${query_string}= catenate ${query_string} AND

Tags: robotframework

I want to append to a variable if dictionary size is greater than 1

```
${queryString}=  startOfString
Run keyword if  ${dictionary_size} > 1
...  ${query_string}=  catenate  ${query_string}  restofString
```

However the only if statement i can see in Robot is the above. Obviously variable assignment isnt a keyword. Is there another way of doing this so i would end up with

startOfString restofString

Answer (score 2):

[Set Variable If](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Variable%20If) is your friend here.

```
${queryString}=    Set Variable    startOfString
&{dict}=    Create Dictionary    foo=bar
${dictLen}=    Get Length    ${dict}
${queryString}=    Set Variable If    ${dictLen} > 1    ${queryString} restofString    ${queryString}
```

If the start of the query is static:

```
&{dict}=    Create Dictionary    foo=bar    zaz=lop
${dictLen}=    Get Length    ${dict}
${queryString}=    Set Variable If    ${dictLen} > 1    startOfString restofString    startOfString
```